# C# Regex match anything inside Parentheses

Tags: c#, regex, parentheses

I want to match anything inside parentheses but the result must exclude the parentheses as well.

**Examples:**
Initialize(P90W)
Brake(45X)

**Result:**
990W
45X

note results without the Parentheses.

I've been trying to make this work but to no avail I tried a few variations but I know it's a simple thing I'm missing and I don't want to go using Replace to achieve it.

```
var item = "Brake(45X)"
Regex searchTerm = new Regex(@"\((.*)\)");
var value = (searchTerm.Match(item).Groups.Count > 0) ?
    searchTerm.Match(item).Groups[0].Value : string.Empty;
```

Comment: I don't know C#, but is a `new Regex()` assumed to be Basic, Extended, or PREG?  Have you tried switching which set of brackets are escaped with backslashes?  Perhaps `\(` means "mark start of range" and `(` is a literal paren?

Comment: This looks fine to me, what is happening?  `value` is `string.Empty`?

Comment: value is returning (P90W) or (45X) with the parentheses.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Some people accuse me of using zero width assertions all the time:

```
resultString = Regex.Match(subjectString, @"(?<=\().+?(?=\))").Value;
```

But they do exactly what you want. Don't capture what you don't want to capture.

Comment: Why do you need lookahead and lookbehind? `@"\(([^\)]*)\)"` is much simpler, and 4 characters shorter :)

Comment: This is great, kol's comment is great as well, but I will say that FailedDev's answer taught me to do something I didn't know before

Comment: 10 years later but with the comment from @kol you need to use `Regex.Match(...).Groups[1]` which is not the case with the answer from @FailedDev

Answer (score 12):

try regex `@"\((.*?)\)"`

EDIT: Also the result will be group 1 not 0, group 0 should contain the entire regex result, not the first parenthesized value

Comment: Useful! I needed to find all string parts inside curly brackets, so used this simple code:
    string pattern = @"{(.*?)}";
    MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(text, pattern);

Answer (score 3):

Remove the inner paranthesis and try again:

```
new Regex(@"(\([^\)]+\))");
```

When you do not escape paranthesis in regex, if you are using group match it will only return the content within the paranthesis. So if you have, `new Regex(@'(a)(b))'`, match 1 will be a and match 2 will be b. Match 0 is the entire match.

Comment: One comment, if you want too empty paranthesis: (\([^\)]*\))

Answer (score 0):

```
Regex searchTerm = new Regex(@"\(([^\)]*)\)");
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
var pattern = @".*public.*(.*\(.*\))";
Regex.Matches(input,pattern)
```