# How to include separators in the regex match result?

Tags: c++, regex, matchevaluator

Currently, I am doing search and replace using this pattern:
`"(?<=\\{).+?(?=\\})"`. This finds everything inside curly brackets. (Courtesy of https://stackoverflow.com/a/8526268/1143917)

I use 'MatchEvaluator' with a delegate, so, when the input string is `{this} is a {string}`, the delegate receives `this` and `string`.

This is not good for me because I want to replace both the matches and the curly brackets.

How do I change my regex expression so the delegate will receive matches with the curly brackets included, i.e. `{this}` and `{string}`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the positve lookbehind and positive lookahead, and just use the brackets:

```
 "\\{[^\\}]+\\}"
```

I can't be sure about this because I've never used regular expressions with C++, but the principle is match `{`, plus all characters that are not `}`, plus `}`.