# Taking part of string based on multiple delimiters?

Tags: c#, string, split, delimiter

I have a string with parentheses and I wish to extract only the portion of the string inside the parentheses.

For example, from the following string:

```
"abc(def)ghi"
```

I'd like to get `"def"`, with no parentheses.

I have done some searching but the closest thing I've found so far is String.Split():

```
string s = "3,2,4,5,6";
string[] words = s.Split(',');
```

But String.Split only takes 1 delimiter at a time.  Is there a better way to grab only the string inside the parentheses?

Comment: You can use a Regex like the one shown here http://stackoverflow.com/a/8526268/187697

Comment: You can add as many delimiters as you like: s.Split('(',')') should work  in your case.

Answer (score 7):

Regex can help here

```
string input = "abc(def)ghi";
var def = Regex.Match(input, @"\((.+?)\)").Groups[1].Value;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can split on multiple chars: `s.Split("()".ToCharArray())`. Not sure whether that is the right solution for you, or a regex is.

Comment: You dont need to convert the string to char array. You can simply write s.Split('(',')')

Answer (score 1):

You can pass in an array of chars to split on.

Like so:

```
string s = "abc(def)ghi";
char[] chars = new char[] { '(', ')' };
string[] parts = s.Split(chars);
```

Comment: It will split the string whenever a character matches one of the characters in the char-array. No matter in which order they are entered (both in the array and in the string to be split).

Comment: if you expecting parts[0] to be "abc", parts[1] to be "def" and parts[2] to be "ghi" then - yes - it would - just like ThoBa stated.

Comment: @L.B if you expect it to be the same result as `abc(def)ghi`, yes.

Answer (score 0):

Just another alternative. Simple, double split

```
        string s = "abc(def)ghi";
        string []first = s.Split('(');
        string[] second = first[1].Split(')');
        Console.WriteLine(second[0]);
        Console.ReadLine();
```